# How to keep track of process status of nested entities

Tags: java, spring-batch

I'm working on setting up a Job which processes the following data structures:

```
class A { long id; List<B> bList; }
class B { long id; list<C> cList; }
class C { long id; }
```

As of now, I've set up a Job with one step containing:

- `ItemReader<C>`: Read A's & B's and combine all of their C's into a list. Return one at a time
- `ItemProcessor<C, C>`
- `ItemWriter<Identifiable>` (implements `long getId();`
- `SkipListener<Identifiable, Identifiable>`

The job processes items of C and write the processing state of each item to a database table.

However; I'd like to process items like this:

1. For every A, process it's B's. Write to table that A is IN_PROGRESS
2. For every B, process it's C's. Write to table that B is IN_PROGRESS
3. Process every C and write to table that C is IN_PROGRESS->COMPLETED/FAILURE
4. All C's are processed. If all is COMPLETED, write to table that B is COMPLETED
5. All B's are processed. If all is COMPLETED, write to table that A is completed.

How would I go about to do this in Spring Batch?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can decompose your job into different steps as you described them in the list. Steps 1, 2, and 3 would be chunk-oriented steps, and Steps 4 and 5 could be tasklets.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine How can keep the relations of the items across steps? I need to know if all C's are COMPLETED in order to update the B as COMPLETED. Do I need to keep track of the parent on each C?
I'd like to do this in a generic way for reuse in other jobs.

Comment: This is not specific to Spring Batch. I think you need to design a solution to the problem you are trying to solve (find the right algorithm) before looking at how to implement it with Spring Batch.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Ok, so Spring Batch does not suppert processing items like I'm trying to do out-of-the-box?
I'm working on a solution atm. Thanks.

Comment: No, what Spring Batch provides OOTB is the [chunk-oriented processing model](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/step.html#chunkOrientedProcessing). It is up to you to decompose the problem into steps and use that model as needed. As mentioned previously, for example your steps 1, 2, and 3 could be chunk-oriented steps, and steps 4 and 5 could be tasklets. Now, how to maintain links, store intermediate results, etc is what you need to figure out in your solution to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: Thanks. I've used the same idea as the AggregateItem from the samples at https://github.com/langmi/spring-batch/tree/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/domain/multiline. Each item have a link to their parent, which makes it possible to save status from parents when the tail item is behing processed

Comment: That's a good idea! Glad you found a solution to your problem.